# Does clients requests always send cookies?

Tags: asp.net, html, cookies, request

In each `request/response` , the cookies are being sent back and forward.

what about :

```
<img src='myPic.jpg' />
```

does the browser sends the cookies also for that request ?

if, so : is there any switch that tells : "*for pictures type , do not send the cookies*".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if so : is there any switch that tells : "for pictures type , do not send the cookies".

Sort of. What you can do is serve pictures off a separate domain. StackOverflow, for example, uses [sstatic.net](http://sstatic.net/). As long as you never, ever, ever set a cookie on that separate domain, all requests to it will lack any cookies, which can have positive performance implications if you like to put a lot of data in your site's cookies.

Comment: so by default - it does send the cookie ?

Comment: Yes, if it's on a domain with any cookies, it'll send the cookies even for images. The browser doesn't really know what an image is at the HTTP request point - you could serve HTML at myPic.jpg if you felt like it using a content-type header.

Comment: For a small site, yes. For a large site like StackOverflow the $8 or so it costs for a domain is absolutely trivial.

Answer (score 2):

No, they **have to** send them on every request as they cannot know if the image is e.g. only available for authenticated users.

That's why large websites often use separate domains for their static resources - not having any cookies associated with those domains makes the http requests a little bit smaller.

Comment: Well, they don't have to. It'd be entirely possible to write a browser that didn't.

Comment: I'm sure that's disallowed by some RFCs. But of course nobody could sue you for writing a browser that ignores MUST-features from RFCs ;)